# Can typescript typing ensure the function will return the requested keys?

Tags: typescript

Some web services supply stuff based on the requested properties. I want to create a function that takes the properties, internally calls the web service and returns the requested data.

The function using the data should now know that the specific key is not undefined now.

While searching for a solution myself I found some things that might help but I was not able to create something useful from them:

- [NonNullable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullablet)
- [Pick](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktk)
- [Is it possible to extract keys from a parameter for type inference in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47388407/is-it-possible-to-extract-keys-from-a-parameter-for-type-inference-in-typescript)
- [Typescript: constrain argument of function to be a key of an object associated with a value of a particular type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52188399/typescript-constrain-argument-of-function-to-be-a-key-of-an-object-associated-w)

Also something that is an extra hassle: There are default properties that are always there like id in this case.

```js
    interface Something {
        id: string;
        foo?: string;
        bar?: number;
    }

    // use 'keyof Something' in some ways here?
    type OptionalProp = 'foo' | 'bar'

    type SomethingSpecific<K extends keyof Something> = {
        [k in K]: NonNullable<Something[k]>
    };

    function get(properties: OptionalProp[]): Something {
        const result: Something = {
            id: '1337'
        };

        if (properties.includes('foo')) {
            result.foo = 'bar';
        }

        if (properties.includes('bar')) {
            result.bar = 42;
        }

        return result;
    }

    console.log(usage());
    function usage(): number {
        const result = get(['bar']);
        return result.bar * 1;
    }
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 1):

So, there is [a way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49579497/2887218) to determine which keys of a type are optional, and you can also provide a call signature for the `get()` function which promises to return a `Something` with some of the formerly-optional properties now being required (it is best if you make it a function of one [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) so that the implementation signature can stay as loose as before; otherwise you will get a lot of complaints in the implementation).  Also note that there is a type alias called [`Required<T>`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.3.1/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1428-L1433) in the standard library that takes an object type `T` and returns a new type where all optional properties are now required.  Using a combination of `Required<T>` and `Pick<T, K>` and [an intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) should work:

```
interface Something {
  id: string;
  foo?: string;
  bar?: number;
}

// get the optional keys of an object type
type OptionalKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: {} extends Pick<T, K> ? K : never }[keyof T];

type OptionalProp = OptionalKeys<Something>

// make get() a generic function that returns an intersection of Something with
//  a Required<Pick<Something, K>> for the passed-in K parameters

function get<K extends OptionalProp>(
  properties: K[]
): Required<Pick<Something, K>> & Something;
function get(properties: OptionalProp[]): Something {
  // impl here
  return null!
}

const result = get(['bar']);
// const result: Required<Pick<Something, "bar">> & Something
result.bar * 1; // okay now
```

This should work for you.  Note that the returned type of `get()` will be an intersection type like `Required<Pick<Something, "bar">> & Something`.  If you want a more straightforward bag-of-properties object type, you can change the `get()` signature to something uglier for the implementer but nicer for the caller:

```
function get<K extends OptionalProp,
  R extends Something=Required<Pick<Something, K>> & Something
>(properties: K[]): { [P in keyof R]: R[P] };
function get(properties: OptionalProp[]): Something { /* impl */ }
  // impl here
  return null!
}

const result = get(['bar']);
//const result: {
//    bar: number;
//    id: string;
//    foo?: string | undefined;
//}
```

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!